# Multiple choices select with data module created view

Tags: forms

on my website I have a custom table, and I used the data module to create a view that uses the entries in that table.
I have created an exposed filter for one of the columns. Since I needed a select form and only search box was available, I used this code:

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {

$form['myfield']['#type'] = 'select';
$form['myfield']['#multiple'] = true;
$form['myfield']['#default_value'] = array("" => "All");
$form['myfield']['#options'] = $values;
$form['myfield']['#attributes'] = array('size' => 10);
```

}

The problem is that when I select multiple values, it performs an "AND", but I need an "OR".
How can I procede?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*markus_petrux* answered, and *josepvalis* gave a helpful [example of this](https://groups.drupal.org/node/82219#comment-255754) in Drupal Groups in 2010.

You can use [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7) to alter the filter to use 'OR'. Trimming *josepvalis*'s example, try redefining the filter & applying that:

```
function my_module_views_pre_view(&$view) {
    $new_view_filters['field_multiselect_value'] = array(
        'id' => 'field_multiselect_value',
        'table' => 'my_table',
        'field' => 'my_column',
        'operator' => 'or',
        'value' => $array_of_values,
        'group' => '0',
        'exposed' => FALSE,
        'relationship' => 'none',
    );
    $view_overrides = array();
    $view_overrides['filters'] = $new_view_filters;
    foreach ($view_overrides as $option => $definition) {
        $view->display_handler->override_option($option, $definition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I couldn't make your solution work, but starting from there I found something that worked. It's probably a bit hacky, but I used a hook_views_query_alter and I set the where condition operator to 'IN'.

Comment: Hmmm, would you mind posting your solution, please? You may have the better answer.

Comment: Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/k2R1fy32 . Sorry, I couldn't format the code here in the comment section. It's very hacky, since I'm targeting specific array indexes... basically I'm just setting the operator to 'IN'. Then I'm also unsetting the condition if the value is set to empty string to have a "SHOW ALL" option. It's horrible, but I needed something quick.

Comment: I have updated the code a bit, much less ugly: http://pastebin.com/FXzMKxe6